# How can I use a variable to access the fieldname of a ruby object in erb? ex. Model.task_#{variable}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have a to-do list with 5 tasks that are stored on the same record.

```
Todo.task_one, Todo.task_two, etc.
```

What I would like to do is be able to loop through the fields like this

```
total_tasks = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
for tasks in total_tasks
Todo.task_#{tasks} = "text here"
end
```

However, this doesn't work unless I use `eval "Todo.task_#{tasks} = 'text here'"` which I know isn't safe.  Even using `eval` isn't really the solution, because I need to do this in the view using `erb`, so I'm kind of stuck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby is full of metaprogramming utilities. One such utility is `Object#send`.

```
["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"].each do |task|
  Task.send("task_#{task}=", "text here")
end
```

Another option is to not give the tasks human friendly method names.

```
5.times do |i|
  Task.tasks[i] = "foo"
end
```

Comment: Worked great! Thanks. Also, it can be used in reverse: task_text = Task.send("task_#{task_number}")

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [send](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332) method that all Ruby objects have. It allows you to 'send' a message (which is what calling a method really is anyways) with a string.

Example:

```
Todo.send("task_#{tasks}")
```

It will return whatever your task methods return.